# A good plane geometry problem on circles

Tags: geometry

$[AB]$ is diameter of a circle, centered at $O$, with radius $a$. A chord $[AD]$ is drawn and extended to meet the tangent through $B$ at point $C$. Point $E$ is taken on $[AC]$ such that $AE=DC$. Denoting the distances of $E$ from the tangent through $A$ and from $(AB)$ by $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Prove that $2ay^2=x^3+xy^2$

[image]

Comment: One has to find the equation of a locus ... I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: it is not about finding locus but to find the relation between x and y

Comment: I am using the language of analytic geometry (cartesian coordinates): do you want an analytic approach or a synthetic one ?

Comment: @metacompactness : What software did you use to create this illustration?

Comment: Whoever down-voted this should explain their objections.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The objection might be that this is yet another (apparent) do-my-homework-for-me problem from OP. I've answered three of them so far, so I'm not totally against such things. That said, one might hope that by the 10th question (and after a few nudges from others), OP would stop (apparently) treating this site like an on-demand answer factory and start providing information to help *us* frame our answers. Of course, the designated way to protest such questions is by voting to close, not by down-voting. (I'm doing neither, but I plan to ignore this user's questions for a while.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I used Adobe Illustrator

Comment: @metacompactness : Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay ... one more ...

[image: Figures]

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2a}{|BD|} = \frac{|AE|}{y} \qquad \qquad &\qquad \qquad \qquad \frac{|BD|}{|CD|} = \frac{x}{y} \\[10pt]
\implies \frac{2a}{|BD|} \cdot \frac{|BD|}{|CD|} &= \frac{|AE|}{y} \cdot \frac{x}{y} \\[10pt]
\implies \qquad\qquad 2a y^2 &= x \; |AE| \; |CD| = x \; |AE|^2 = x \left( x^2 + y^2 \right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: is this GeoGebra?

Comment: @metacompactness: This is GeoGebra. (The interface affronts my software design sensibilities in many ways, but, hey ... it's free! It's also pretty powerful and easy to use, so I guess I can give it some leeway, interface-wise. :)

Answer (score 1):

Call $F$ the orthogonal projection of $D$ on $AB$.
Then the [intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) says that $BF=x$.
Also the [right triangle altitude theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle_altitude_theorem) says that $$DF^2=x(2a-x)$$ because $ADB$ is right in $D$.
Now from the similarity of two right triangles (which ?) you have $$DF= \frac {(2a-x)y}{x}$$
Therefore $$x(2a-x)=\frac {(2a-x)^2y^2}{x^2}$$
After dividing both sides by $2a-x$ (you can suppose $x \neq 2a$), you obtain the relation.